# How can I get the height from bottom of the layout to top of my Recyclerview programatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView, I want to set it's height from it's top to bottom of the fragment's layout?

I tried to get Y-axis of recyclerview

```
 float yAxis = recyclerView.getY();
```

but I have no idea what to do next

Comment: Hello, why you need get height recyclerview?

Comment: because I want it

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
recyclerview.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: recyclerviews' layout params or layouts params?

Comment: @egorr33 if you want your recyclerview to fit the parent fragment's height, set the layout params of your recyclerview to matchparent, provided recyclerview is the direct child of root layout